# How can I run recursive `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` while abiding by `.gitignore`?

Tags: emacs, gitignore, dired

An Emacs dired buffer for `~/.` is open.

I move the cursor to `~/proj` and do the `C-u i -alR`  dance (recursive `dired-maybe-insert-subdir`).

But the folder `~/proj` has a subfolder `~/proj/.git` and a file `~/proj/.gitignore`.

How can I run recursive `dired-maybe-insert-subdir` while ignoring the files and folders that appear in `~/proj/.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question.

But if you can't omit the particular files or subdirs you want to omit by using `ls` switches, you can perhaps omit them by using `dired-omit-mode` (`C-x M-o`) or `dired-hide-subdir` (`$`).

(For `dired-omit-mode` you need to load standard library `dired-x`.)